# What generated my "appengine-web.xml" file?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I inherited a Java app that is configured to run in Google App Engine. My pom includes the **com.google.appengine.appengine-maven-plugin** plugin, which may or may not be related to this question.

In my src directory, in the WEB-INF directory, I have a "app.yaml" file. But when my project is built into a war, the target directory has both a "app.yaml" file and a "appengine-web.xml" file. How did this "appengine-web.xml" file get here?

The first line of this "appengine-web.xml" file says `<!-- Generated from app.yaml. Do not edit. -->`. If this file was generated from an "app.yaml" file, then what generated it? Which plugin/function has created this file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was a non-documented feature of App Engine Maven Plugin that was removed about two years ago.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/426#issuecomment-665757462

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official documentation [appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref):

> App Engine Java applications use a configuration file, named appengine-web.xml, to specify information about your app and to identify which files in the app's WAR file are static files (like images) and which are resource files used by the application.

So, this is created by default, by the App Engine environment,  when using the App Engine Maven plugin, so you can handle some specific settings and configurations. You can find more details on these settings [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#syntax), but it includes the setting of environment variables, how to scale the application - manual, basic or automatic - etc. In addition to that, you can check this example of a [sample app](https://github.com/sendgrid/google-java-sample-app) that is deployed into war and the file is created as well. **Please, bear in mind that this is only on Java 8.**

To summarize, this file is created by the App Engine environment when using this plugin, not by a specific function. In this official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#creating_a_new_project), it indicates this as well:

> The artifact you used to create the project has done the basic src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml configuration for you

So, this confirms that it was created via the plugin. Besides that, it shows the message of the relation with `app.yaml`, because they work together and each one of them has a specific use and settings that are needed for your application to work correctly.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: You're confident that the file was created by the App Engine Environment, and not the App Engine Maven Plugin? 

I ask because the file stopped being auto-generated after I updated to the newer version of the App Engine Maven Plugin. So I want to be sure whether that change is related.

Comment: Hi @MathewAlden yes, it's created by the plugin, as it's only related to Java application as well, sorry if I was not so clear in my answer at first - I appreciate you posting an answer as well, with the confirmation your received from the developers of the plugin. I would appreciate if you could remove your downvote, due to the fact that I couldn't edit my answer before you posted yours. :)

Comment: Sorry I was a little hasty to downvote; I've undone that. However, although your answer is correct, I'm not sure that the source you cited for your answer is relevant. The URL you provided in paragraph 4 is talking about the *archetype* generating an appengline-web.xml; in my case the appengine-web.xml is being generated without an archetype, which - according to the devs - is an undocumented feature that was removed about 2 years ago.

Comment: Furthermore, your answer says that app.yaml is "needed for your application to work correctly". But I though app.yaml was only needed when deploying to a flexible server? Which means that it's not needed in many app which run on the standard server. Right?

Comment: Thanks for removing the downvote :) . Sure, I understand your doubts. As clarified in the links that I provided, it's deprecated, in case you are not using that Maven plugin, because it's recommended to use Cloud SDK now - as informed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven). I would recommend you to raise a bug in [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0), in case you want this to be changed in the documentation.

Comment: About your question regarding `app.yaml` it exists for both environments: Flex and Standard. You can find more information on the configuration and usage of this file in Standard environment in the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref).